# What is wrong with this pandas dataframe.apply(lambda)?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, dataframe

I cannot understand why this code does not work. I am practicing df.apply with lambda. I expect the output to be a sorted df. Thanks.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randn(10,5)
col = list('ABCDE') # assign column names
```

I want to create a new dataframe t that is a sorted df

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = col)    
t = df.apply(lambda x: x.sort_values()) 

>>> df    
          A         B         C         D         E
0  1.548097  0.682373 -1.254562 -0.249815  0.002013
1 -2.581173  0.946034 -1.389210 -0.877128 -1.569914
2 -0.980636  1.555700 -1.346029  0.180983  1.112470
3  0.724657  0.520718  0.122696  1.386643  0.060714
4 -0.119740 -0.665260 -1.085457  0.699085  1.149364
5 -0.004628 -0.479672 -0.641696  0.875471  0.826836
6  0.598497 -0.018560 -1.002511  0.478659  0.463565
7 -0.005159 -0.137165 -0.460209  0.284940  0.755981
8  0.576421  0.098833 -2.664028  0.118074 -0.426393
9 -0.223696 -0.589748 -0.733454 -0.254564 -0.519015

>>> t  
          A         B         C         D         E
0  1.548097  0.682373 -1.254562 -0.249815  0.002013
1 -2.581173  0.946034 -1.389210 -0.877128 -1.569914
2 -0.980636  1.555700 -1.346029  0.180983  1.112470
3  0.724657  0.520718  0.122696  1.386643  0.060714
4 -0.119740 -0.665260 -1.085457  0.699085  1.149364
5 -0.004628 -0.479672 -0.641696  0.875471  0.826836
6  0.598497 -0.018560 -1.002511  0.478659  0.463565
7 -0.005159 -0.137165 -0.460209  0.284940  0.755981
8  0.576421  0.098833 -2.664028  0.118074 -0.426393
9 -0.223696 -0.589748 -0.733454 -0.254564 -0.519015
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming your question is: Why doesn't your code do what you wanted?

the `.apply(lambda x: x.sort_values())` does do what you want.  However, the return type of this lambda is a `pd.Series` and it has an index that is preserved.  When recombining all columns, pandas ensures the indices are lined up, thus removing the sort you just did. In order to break that behavior, get at the values (without the index)

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.sort_values().values)
```

Comment: Your solution is spot on. Thank you so much for clarifying this.